# Construct an object of fitobject (cfit) with a vector of parameters in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

Is there a possibility to construct a cfit-object with a vector of parameters like:

```
param = [17,-77,95,112];
ft = fittype('poly3');
result = cfit(ft,param);
```

instead of:

```
ft = fittype('poly3');
result = cfit(ft,17,-77,95,112);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) operator `:` together with cell arrays::

```
param = {17,-77,95,112};
result = cfit(ft,param{:});
```

you can get `param` in cell form with `mat2cell`.

Comment: That was one of my ideas before I asked here. This does not work here.

Comment: OK I found the answer:

    param = {17,-77,95,112};
    result = cfit(ft,param{:});

Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't test it, I edited my answer. Thanks for correction!